# How to send message from worker of progressive web app

Tags: javascript

I have a website that is working great using progressive web app. However, I need to display on the website (or inside the web app) if the page was loaded from the cache or from the internet. This code below works great to fetch the content from the internet, otherwise (if the user is offline) it gets the content from the cache:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    
    event.respondWith((async () => {

        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);

        try{
            
            const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);

            cache.put(event.request,fetchResponse.clone());
            
            //modify response body here, appending "ONLINE VERSION" to the end of the returned HTML

            return fetchResponse;
            
        }
        catch(e) {
            
            const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
            
            if (cachedResponse) {
                
                //modify response body here, appending "OFFLINE VERSION" to the end of the returned HTML

                return cachedResponse;
            }
            
        }

    }   

})());
```

After 2 days researching, I came to the conclusion that modifying the response body to change a DOM element to show the message is too complicated, I need to create a `new Response`, preserving status, headers...

Then I came up with another solution: after the worker returns the content to the user, the worker could send a message to the website/app and the website could read the message and manipulate the DOM as needed. My problem so far is using the message!

I tried adding the code below to the bottom of the code of my worker but it's not working because I think the content is being fetched async and the code below runs before the content is returned to the website:

```
const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('xxx');
broadcast.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'ccc') {
    broadcast.postMessage({ "aaa":"bbb" });
  }
};
```

Inside the website I have the code below:

const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('xxx');

```
// Listen to the response
broadcast.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event.data.payload);
};
```

I think it's not working because the message is being sent from the worker to the page before it is ready... so how can I make the worker only send the message after the page is loaded?

Comment: Had an idea... what if you add a event listener in the website JS that would check for the appended element offline/online data once the page is loaded? something like: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{ /* check data here... */ });